# Unable to concatenate two strings and return it from a function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

The following C code is giving segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *getSegment(char *symbol2,char *symbol3,char *filename) {
    if (strcmp(symbol2,"static") == 0) return strcat(filename,symbol3);
}

int main() {
    char *symbol2="static";
    char *symbol3="asdf";
    char *filename="zxcn";
    printf("%s\n",getSegment(symbol2,symbol3,filename));
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to concatenate two strings and return the concatenated string from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `getSegment` function, *per se*, other than the fact that it doesn't return a valid string if the comparison is ***not*** true; rather, you are giving it an invalid third argument (the destination string).

The `filename` variable is a pointer to a **constant** string literal of length 5 characters (the 4 visible ones plus the `nul` terminator). Thus, it is: (a) not modifiable; and (b), even if it were, it is not large enough to hold the result of the concatenation.

To fix this, declare `filename` as a *non-constant* character array that is large enough to store the result of the concatenation. In the code below, I have allowed up to 10 characters (9 plus the terminator), which is enough *in your example*.

To fix the first point, you need to return something in an `else` clause.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* getSegment(char* symbol2, char* symbol3, char* filename)
{
    if (strcmp(symbol2, "static") == 0) return strcat(filename, symbol3);
    else return filename; // return unmodified source string
}

int main()
{
    char* symbol2 = "static";
    char* symbol3 = "asdf";
    char filename[10] = "zxcn"; // Both NON-CONSTANT and LARGE ENOUGH!
    printf("%s\n", getSegment(symbol2, symbol3, filename));
    return 0;
}
```

---

However, note that the `getSegment` function here *modifies* the given `filename` argument (which was the cause of your problem). If you want it to create a new string (from the concatenation or just a copy of the original), then you have to do the allocation of that new string yourself (and you will need to `free` that memory in `main`, when you're done with it).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getSegment(char* symbol2, char* symbol3, char* filename)
{
    if (strcmp(symbol2, "static") == 0) {
        char* answer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(filename) + strlen(symbol3) + 1));
        strcpy(answer, filename);
        strcat(answer, symbol3);
        return answer;
    }
    else {
        return strdup(filename);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* symbol2 = "static";
    char* symbol3 = "asdf";
    char* filename = "zxcn";
    char* result = getSegment(symbol2, symbol3, filename);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to concatenate to filename:

```
return strcat(filename,symbol3)
```

You are forgeting that `filename` has a size of `5`. It has no more space for you to concatenate caracters.

When you assing it like this:

```
    char *filename="zxcn";
```

It should be assigned as a `const char*`. The compiler should warn you on that because writing to it is UB. Instead you should use some `char[]`